# Block IP beginning with, U.F.W

Tags: networking, server, dns, firewall, ufw

Someone is running a registration bot on my site and I have taken steps to prevent the registration, but now I want to block the whole IP range from even being able to access my site.

I have set up UFW on my server, but other than entering each IP individually I cant figure out how to block all IPs beginning with 91.

Or even better yet block *vhoster.org but I dont know how to do that either since I'm new to UFW and ubuntu server all together.

So how can I block this thing for good?

[IP List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXuoM.png)

[NameServer List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGHiN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command for deny whole 91.0.0.0/8 network is

```
 sudo ufw deny from 91.0.0.0/8
```

when you list rules

```
 sudo ufw status
```

you will see

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----  
...
Anywhere                   DENY        91.0.0.0/8
```

This will `deny` any traffic from ip's witch start with 91.x.x.x
But I recommend to use smaller network ranges for deny traffic.
Based on your address list

```
sudo ufw deny from 91.200.12.0/24
sudo ufw deny from 91.213.126.0/24
sudo ufw deny from 91.207.7.0/24
```

`UFW` can not create rule based on logical names aka domains, but you can add rule using `iptables` in chain `ufw-user-input`

```
sudo iptables -A ufw-user-input --src vhoster.org -j DROP
```

this will deny traffic from whole domain `vhoster.org` ip's
To list this rules use command

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Comment: the iptables command gives me 'iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.' so i need to set something up first?

Comment: well enabling ufw first seemed to help lol

Comment: they still seem to be getting through =/
http://i.imgur.com/cpt4D2t.png and yes i cleared the log (a couple times) after adding the rule

Comment: just wanted to confirm, delete the rule and place the blocks at the top using 'ufw insert 1 deny from 91.200.12.0/24'   ?

Comment: To summarize for the benefit of future readers: To block 91.*, use 91.0.0.0/8; to block 91.200.*, use 91.200.0.0/16; to block 91.200.12.*, use 91.200.12.0/24; cf. a related discussion at https://serverfault.com/questions/592061/block-range-of-ip-addresses